# Dividing two summaries of vectors in promQL

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql

I got two vectors that I want to divide in promQL

```
sum(
  increase(filter_counter)[$__range]
) by (type) 
/ 
sum(
  increase(filter_counter)[$__range]
)
```

I want to divide specific filters by their type with the sum of all filters to get an approximate percentage of usage for filters. This operation currently gives out NO DATA and it's invalid.

What's the way I can achieve desired behavior

Comment: Prometheus executes operations over vectors with the same labelsets. Since your LHS has a `type` label and RHS - doesn't you need to apply [vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching-keywords): add `on() group_left()` right after `/`

Answer (score -1):

As poined by the comments, adding `on() group_left()` after the `/` solved the issue